# Can't install caret package on AWS RStudio

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio-server

I have setup RStudio Server on AWS by following Manuel Amunategui's [instructive steps](https://amunategui.github.io/EC2-RStudioServer/index.html). I successfully installed a number of packages by simply typing the "install.packages([package_name])" command into the console and executing it. However when I attempted to install the caret package, I receive an enormous amount of response code, some of which indicate errors, but little of which makes sense to me.

```
Installing package into ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘mnormt’, ‘kernlab’, ‘CVST’, ‘psych’, ‘DRR’, ‘robustbase’, ‘broom’, ‘dimRed’, ‘ddalpha’, ‘gower’, ‘recipes’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mnormt_1.5-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 37169 bytes (36 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 36 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/kernlab_0.9-25.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1170281 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/CVST_0.2-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 12452 bytes (12 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 12 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/psych_1.7.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3311758 bytes (3.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/DRR_0.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 128442 bytes (125 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 125 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/robustbase_0.92-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3479092 bytes (3.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1397648 bytes (1.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dimRed_0.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 70299 bytes (68 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 68 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ddalpha_1.3.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 543279 bytes (530 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 530 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gower_0.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 17393 bytes (16 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 16 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/recipes_0.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 599460 bytes (585 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 585 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/caret_6.0-78.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4726041 bytes (4.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.5 MB

* installing *source* package ‘mnormt’ ...
** package ‘mnormt’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c biv-nt.f -o biv-nt.o
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
biv-nt.f:371:11:

       hs = sign( one, dh - r*dk )
           1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
biv-nt.f:372:11:

       ks = sign( one, dk - r*dh )
           1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c sadmvnt.f -o sadmvnt.o
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
sadmvnt.f:976:3:

  10      END DO
   1
Warning: Label 10 at (1) defined but not used
sadmvnt.f:80:15:

       INFORM = MVNNIT( N, CORREL, LOWER, UPPER, INFIN, INFIS, D, E )
               1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:217:38:

         IF ( MINCLS .LT. 0 ) SBRGNS = WORK(LENWRK)
                                      1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:275:21:

             RGNCLS = RGNCLS*(MESH(DIVAXN)+1)/MESH(DIVAXN)
                     1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:276:21:

             NWRGNS = NWRGNS*(MESH(DIVAXN)+1)/MESH(DIVAXN)
                     1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:1274:24:

                POINTS = PONTRS(SUBTMP)
                        1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:1275:24:

                POINTP = PONTRS(SUBTMP+1)
                        1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:1283:21:

             POINTS = PONTRS(SUBTMP)
                     1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:1303:21:

             POINTS = PONTRS(SUBTMP)
                     1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:324:15:

          TOP = PONTRS(1)
               1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:331:21:

             RGNCLS = RGNCLS*MESH(I)
                     1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:336:18:

          RGNCLS = RGNCLS*(MESH(DIVAXN)+1)/MESH(DIVAXN)
                  1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:1585:3:

  10      END DO
   1
Warning: Label 10 at (1) defined but not used
sadmvnt.f:1432:15:

       INFORM = MVTNIT( N, NU, CORREL, LOWER, UPPER, INFIN, INFIS, D, E )
               1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
sadmvnt.f:1661:0:

      &              /( 1 + BMIN**2/(NU+I-1) )**( (NU+I-2)/TWO )

Warning: ‘bmin’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
sadmvnt.f:1658:0:

      &              /( 1 + AMIN**2/(NU+I-1) )**( (NU+I-2)/TWO )

Warning: ‘amin’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
sadmvnt.f:1127:0:

       INTEGER S, IXCHNG, LXCHNG, I, L

Warning: ‘lxchng’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
sadmvnt.f:804:0:

       END

Warning: ‘__result_bvn’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
sadmvnt.f:762:0:

       DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION BVN ( LOWER, UPPER, INFIN, CORREL )

note: ‘__result_bvn’ was declared here
sadmvnt.f:1046:0:

                   IF ( INFI(I) .EQ. 2 ) Y(I) = ( AMIN + BMIN )/2

Warning: ‘bmin’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
sadmvnt.f:1046:0: Warning: ‘amin’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o mnormt.so biv-nt.o sadmvnt.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mnormt.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mnormt’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/mnormt’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mnormt’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘kernlab’ ...
** package ‘kernlab’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c brweight.cpp -o brweight.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c ctable.cpp -o ctable.o
ctable.cpp: In member function ‘UInt32 ChildTable::up(const UInt32&, UInt32&)’:
ctable.cpp:60:9: warning: variable ‘lcp_idx’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  UInt32 lcp_idx = 0, lcp_prev_idx = 0;
         ^~~~~~~
ctable.cpp:60:22: warning: variable ‘lcp_prev_idx’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  UInt32 lcp_idx = 0, lcp_prev_idx = 0;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c cweight.cpp -o cweight.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dbreakpt.c -o dbreakpt.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dcauchy.c -o dcauchy.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dgpnrm.c -o dgpnrm.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dgpstep.c -o dgpstep.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dprecond.c -o dprecond.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dprsrch.c -o dprsrch.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dspcg.c -o dspcg.o
dspcg.c: In function ‘dspcg’:
dspcg.c:113:40: warning: variable ‘alpha’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  double gfnorm, gfnormf, stol = 1e-16, alpha;
                                        ^~~~~
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dtron.c -o dtron.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dtrpcg.c -o dtrpcg.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c dtrqsol.c -o dtrqsol.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c esa.cpp -o esa.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c expdecayweight.cpp -o expdecayweight.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c inductionsort.cpp -o inductionsort.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c kspectrumweight.cpp -o kspectrumweight.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c lcp.cpp -o lcp.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c misc.c -o misc.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c msufsort.cpp -o msufsort.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c solvebqp.c -o solvebqp.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c stringk.c -o stringk.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c stringkernel.cpp -o stringkernel.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c svm.cpp -o svm.o
svm.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* tron_optim(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)’:
svm.cpp:3888:17: warning: variable ‘s’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     const char* s;
                 ^
svm.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* smo_optim(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)’:
svm.cpp:4189:17: warning: variable ‘s’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     const char* s;
                 ^
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c wkasailcp.cpp -o wkasailcp.o
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c wmsufsort.cpp -o wmsufsort.o
g++ -m64 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o kernlab.so brweight.o ctable.o cweight.o dbreakpt.o dcauchy.o dgpnrm.o dgpstep.o dprecond.o dprsrch.o dspcg.o dtron.o dtrpcg.o dtrqsol.o esa.o expdecayweight.o inductionsort.o kspectrumweight.o lcp.o misc.o msufsort.o solvebqp.o stringk.o stringkernel.o svm.o wkasailcp.o wmsufsort.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [kernlab.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘kernlab’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/kernlab’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘kernlab’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘robustbase’ ...
** package ‘robustbase’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c R-rng4ftn.c -o R-rng4ftn.o
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c eigen.f -o eigen.o
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c lmrob.c -o lmrob.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c mc.c -o mc.o
mc.c: In function ‘mc_C_d’:
mc.c:192:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(i=0; i < 90; i++) Rprintf(" %8g", work[i]); Rprintf("\n  ... ");
   ^~~
mc.c:192:51: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(i=0; i < 90; i++) Rprintf(" %8g", work[i]); Rprintf("\n  ... ");
                                                   ^~~~~~~
mc.c:193:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(i=j-4; i < j; i++)Rprintf(" %8g", work[i]); Rprintf("\n");
   ^~~
mc.c:193:51: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(i=j-4; i < j; i++)Rprintf(" %8g", work[i]); Rprintf("\n");
                                                   ^~~~~~~
mc.c:194:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(i=0; i < 90; i++) Rprintf(" %8d", iwt [i]); Rprintf("\n  ... ");
   ^~~
mc.c:194:51: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(i=0; i < 90; i++) Rprintf(" %8d", iwt [i]); Rprintf("\n  ... ");
                                                   ^~~~~~~
mc.c:195:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(i=j-4; i < j; i++)Rprintf(" %8d", iwt [i]); Rprintf("\n");
   ^~~
mc.c:195:51: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(i=j-4; i < j; i++)Rprintf(" %8d", iwt [i]); Rprintf("\n");
                                                   ^~~~~~~
mc.c:197:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(i=0; i < j; i++) Rprintf(" %8g", work[i]); Rprintf("\n");
   ^~~
mc.c:197:50: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(i=0; i < j; i++) Rprintf(" %8g", work[i]); Rprintf("\n");
                                                  ^~~~~~~
mc.c:198:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(i=0; i < j; i++) Rprintf(" %8d", iwt [i]); Rprintf("\n");
   ^~~
mc.c:198:50: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(i=0; i < j; i++) Rprintf(" %8d", iwt [i]); Rprintf("\n");
                                                  ^~~~~~~
mc.c:240:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(i = 1; i <= i_m; i++) Rprintf(" %2d", p[i]); if(lrg) Rprintf(" ...");
   ^~~
mc.c:240:52: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(i = 1; i <= i_m; i++) Rprintf(" %2d", p[i]); if(lrg) Rprintf(" ...");
                                                    ^~
mc.c:242:3: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
   for(i = 1; i <= i_m; i++) Rprintf(" %2d", q[i]); if(lrg) Rprintf(" ...");
   ^~~
mc.c:242:52: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
   for(i = 1; i <= i_m; i++) Rprintf(" %2d", q[i]); if(lrg) Rprintf(" ...");
                                                    ^~
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c monitor.c -o monitor.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c qn_sn.c -o qn_sn.o
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c rf-common.f -o rf-common.o
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c rffastmcd.f -o rffastmcd.o
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c rfltsreg.f -o rfltsreg.o
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
gfortran -m64   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules  -c rllarsbi.f -o rllarsbi.o
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c rob-utils.c -o rob-utils.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c rowMedians.c -o rowMedians.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c wgt_himed.c -o wgt_himed.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o robustbase.so R-rng4ftn.o eigen.o init.o lmrob.o mc.o monitor.o qn_sn.o rf-common.o rffastmcd.o rfltsreg.o rllarsbi.o rob-utils.o rowMedians.o wgt_himed.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [robustbase.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘robustbase’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/robustbase’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘robustbase’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘gower’ ...
** package ‘gower’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c R_register_native.c -o R_register_native.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c gower.c -o gower.o
gower.c:24:10: fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <omp.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [gower.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gower’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gower’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gower’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘kernlab’ is not available for package ‘CVST’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/CVST’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘CVST’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available for package ‘psych’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/psych’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘psych’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘robustbase’ is not available for package ‘ddalpha’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ddalpha’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ddalpha’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘kernlab’, ‘CVST’ are not available for package ‘DRR’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/DRR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘DRR’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘psych’ is not available for package ‘broom’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/broom’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘DRR’ is not available for package ‘dimRed’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/dimRed’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dimRed’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘dimRed’, ‘ddalpha’, ‘gower’ are not available for package ‘recipes’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/recipes’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘recipes’ is not available for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘/home/[user_name]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/caret’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpbfYaUk/downloaded_packages’
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here? Do I need to increase the available memory (I'm currently using the free tier, while I figure out the basics).

Comment: So many library you didn't install, try to install them.

Comment: I believe R auto-installs dependencies

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxxx` mean **you didn't install the right libraries**

Comment: `fatal error: xxx.h: No such file or directory` mean **you didn't install the right header for xxx**